# Writing in a file goes wrong

Tags: java, scala, file, io

Hello I am trying to add a line to a file using scala.

I tried this

```
 val pw =  new FileWriter("src/test/resources/config") 
 pw.write("file contents")
 pw.append("keke")
 pw.flush() 
 pw.close()
```

The file is created but nothing in it :/.

Comment: Writing + printing = wrinting? 

Answer (score -1):

Works for me:

```
% mkdir -p src/test/resources
% /usr/local/scala/scala-2.13.8/bin/scala
Welcome to Scala 2.13.8 (OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM, Java 17.0.2).
Type in expressions for evaluation. Or try :help.

scala> import java.io.FileWriter
import java.io.FileWriter

scala> val pw =  new FileWriter("src/test/resources/config") 
     |  pw.write("file contents")
     |  pw.append("keke")
     |  pw.flush() 
     |  pw.close()
val pw: java.io.FileWriter = java.io.FileWriter@241fbec

scala> 
:quit

% cat src/test/resources/config 
file contentskeke%
```

But note that the file doesn't end with a newline character (because your code doesn't do anything that would add one). This can confuse some tools. Perhaps you are mistaken that the resulting file is empty. What method are you using for determining that it is empty?